# ReadFile() Output to WinAPI edit Dialog

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, command-line, dialog

Ok, let's see if this all makes sense. Today, as I began working on a small project, I ran into an error I can't seem to get over. The function of the program I am working on is to read data from a pipe (which is the output of another program) and update an HWND ("edit") control dialog using WinAPI. Now, I've been successful at updating the dialog: sort of. If I send the character buffer from the ::ReadFile() function to the dialog, I get the proper output but with a ton of extra characters I don't want. So how can I simply strip it to the output I'm looking for, or is there a better way to accomplish what I'm attempting? Perhaps take the output and WriteFile(); or something similar to decipherable text?

Here is what's happening:

> some output...'Hola Mondo' means... Hello word!ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ$

Here is what I want to happen:

> some output...'Hola Mondo' means...
>
> Hello word!

Thanks so much for your help!

Regards,
Dennis M.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the "Bytes Read" output argument of ReadFile so you know how long the string is, then put a terminating NUL (`'\0') character at that offset.

Comment: You guys are fantastic! Thanks so much. Such a little thing just escaping me. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're not 0-terminating your buffer before passing it to the text updating function.

Check the 'Example: Open a File for Reading' from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb540534%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to add a '\0' termination character to the string you're passing to the edit control.

But your question should show the code including the `ReadFile()` and where you pass the data to the edit control so someone can say for sure (and give a better suggestion).